# Using an array with different classes

Tags: java, arrays, methods, switch-statement

public class Business_Software_MainMenu

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true){

        System.out.println("MAIN MENU");
        System.out.print("\n1. Create new client\n2. Create new product\n3. Create new invoice\n4. Summary by client\n5. Summary by product");
        System.out.print("\n\nEnter choice : ");    
        int menuchoice = Keyboard.readInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        if (menuchoice>0 & menuchoice<6){

            switch (menuchoice){

            case 1:
                //create new client
                Business_Software_Obj client = new Business_Software_Obj();
                client.client();
                break;

            case 2:
                //create new product

            case 3: 
                //create new invoice
                Business_Software_Obj invoice = new Business_Software_Obj();
                invoice.invoice();
                break;

            case 4:
                //summary report by client
                Business_Software_Obj clientsummary = new Business_Software_Obj();
                clientsummary.clientsummary();
                break;

            case 5:
                //summary report by product

            default: 
                System.out.print("Invalid choice, try again");


            }

        }

    }

}
```

public class Business_Software_Obj

```
public int clientnamenum = 0;
public int clientbalancenum = 0;

public String[] clientname = new String[1000];
public long[] clientbalance = new long[1000];

public void invoice(){

    // This method creates an invoice

    char answer;
    long sum = 0;
    int descnum = 0;
    int descnumloop;
    int pricenum = 0;

    String[] description = new String[100]; //creates an array for products/services
    int[] price = new int[100]; //creates an array for the prices of the items

    System.out.print("Enter invoice #\t\t: ");
    String invoicenum = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the invoice number

    System.out.print("Enter Date\t\t: ");
    String date = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the date of the invoice

    System.out.print("Enter client name\t: ");
    String recipient = Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the recipient of the invoice

    do{

        System.out.print("\nDescription of service or product  : ");
        description[descnum++] =  Keyboard.readString(); //user inputs the description of the service/product       

        System.out.print("Price of service or product   (€)  : ");
        price[pricenum++] = Keyboard.readInt(); //user inputs the price of the item

        System.out.print("\nAdd another service/product? (Y/N) : ");
        answer = Keyboard.readChar(); //User chooses whether he wishes to add another item


        }while(answer=='Y' || answer=='y'); //loops if answer is yes

    System.out.println("\nInvoice # " + invoicenum); 
    System.out.println("Date : " + date);
    System.out.println("Bill to : " + recipient); 

    System.out.println("\nITEM\t\t\t\t€");


    for (descnumloop = 0; descnumloop < descnum; descnumloop++){
        System.out.print ("\n" + description [descnumloop]); //prints all item descriptions
        System.out.print ("\t\t\t\t" + price [descnumloop]); //prints all item prices
    }


    for (int i : price){
        sum += i; //calculates total of all items
    }

    System.out.print("\nTOTAL\t\t\t\t" + sum+"\n\n");

    return;

}

public void client(){

    //this method creates a new client

    System.out.print("Enter client name : ");
    clientname[clientnamenum++] = Keyboard.readString();

    System.out.print("Enter client opening balance : ");
    clientbalance[clientbalancenum++] = Keyboard.readLong();
    System.out.print("\n");

}

public void clientsummary(){

    System.out.println("Test");

    for (int clientnamenumloop = 0; clientnamenumloop < clientnamenum; clientnamenumloop++){
        System.out.print ("\n" + clientname[clientnamenumloop]); //prints all clients

    }

}
```

The method to create a new product and show a product summary have not been created yet, so ignore those. My problem lies with creating new clients in one method, and then using another method to print out the list of clients. Right now when i run this, there is no output for case 4. What can I do to fix this so that i am able to output all clients inputted?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new objects at every `case`. When you are creating new instance, all the non-static variables you have in that class (`clientname`, `clientbalance` etc.) are created for that instance, they are brand new (arrays don't have your data, `ints` are initialized to `0` etc.). What you need to do is either add `static` keyword before all those variables, that will make them tied to the class itself, not the instance (they will stay the same when you create new instances) - I do not suggest that solution. Another solution - make your `Business_Software_Obj` an instance variable in the `MainMenu` class, put this before the `main` method:

`private Business_Software_Obj bso = new Business_Software_Obj();`

Then in your cases use that variable, don't create new object again, leave it like that:

`case 1: client.client(); break;`

Same in other cases. You already have that object, it will be shared in all your cases.

Comment: The first solution of adding static before the variable worked, but i couldnt get the preferred solution to work. When i type case1: client.client(); , the first client "cannot be resolved".

Comment: Ye the instance variable I was talking about, you are using it here, so you need to use it's name, if you named it like it did in my post (`bso`) then you need to do `bso.client()`, in `case 2` you need `bso.invoice()` etc.

Comment: Now it tells me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field bso"

Comment: That's, because main method is static, add `static` to the `bso` field and it will work. Or you can create an instance of your `MainMenu`, but that's not necessary here I guess. Remember, if you use that solution then fields from solution number 1 don't have to be static (and shouldn't be).

Comment: It worked using `private static Business_Software_Obj bso = new Business_Software_Obj();` . Thanks for your help